# Qt5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, qt, pyqt5

I have followed this

https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

But when I try

qmake --version

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

I usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu,I have

```
qt4:
bin  plugins

qt5:
bin  libexec  mkspecs  plugins  qml

qtchooser:
4.conf  5.conf  qt4.conf  qt5.conf

qt-default:
qtchooser
```

Why?

Comment: Where did it install Qt to? BTW, Qt5 is already installed in Ubuntu 16.04. If you need the dev tools, you can just install them from the archive as well.

Comment: @dobey Take a look at my edit,please!